# How to develop with the Bitcoin cash?

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I have a simple wallet created with the `BitcoinJ`. I can create the address, track the transactions, check account balance etc with the wallet.

I would like to extend the wallet for the `Bitcoin cash` and was wondering is there any framework/library available for this forked currency?

Comment: It is still early days for bitcoin cash.  I believe you would need to implement the differences between bitcoin and bitcoin cash into BitcoinJ in order to be able to have BitcoinJ connected to the Bitcoin Cash network

Comment: There is a Scala project based on BitcoinJ. It has BCH signing code too: See https://github.com/scalahub/bitcoinS/blob/master/BitcoinS_Tests/src/sh/TestUAHF.scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bitcoinj.cash project currently being put together.  The code is not ready for use but should be by next week: https://github.com/bitcoinj-cash/bitcoinj